# How to Remove a frame from an HEVC bitstream?

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding, codec, hevc, bitstream

I have an HEVC encoded bitstream (.bin and equivalent .mp4 file). I want to remove some frames from the bitstream to see how a decoder (or media player) behaves when a particular frame is lost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoyK7.png)

How I can remove a frame (or a NAL unit) from the bitstream? What tools can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ffmpeg, you can use the drop option of the [noise](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#noise) bitstream filter.

```
ffmpeg -i IN -c copy -bsf:v noise=drop=between(n\,20\,30) OUT
```

This will drop packets #20-30 from the video stream. This bsf is codec-agnostic.

For a few codecs (H.264, H.265, MJPEG, MPEG2, VP9, AV1), you have the [filter_units](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#filter_005funits) bsf.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i IN -c copy -bsf:v 'filter_units=remove_types=35|38-40' OUT
```

The unit type values will depend on the codec. Consult the codec standard document for nal_unit_type or a similar parameter.